# CSS / JavaScript slider animation issue using safari

Tags: jquery, css, animation, safari, slider

I'm currently building a website for a client and I'm using code from [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/07/slider-gallery/)

My client unfortunately won't allow me to post the link of my current work as it has sensitive information. However above is a clear example of what i'm using.

The issue:

I'm using text as a description next to the images on the slider. They are currently sat next each image using margin and has its own div. In Safari, this text will distort and be over the top of the text and seems to ignore the rules I have put down and either sit on top of the image or move across to the right. I've no idea why its doing this and doesn't happen at all in the other browsers. I've changed the java variables so the whole container is bigger but this seems to make no difference. It is odd that on some occassions it displays fine when refreshing the page but it seems there is no pattern to this and i've not seen anything odd in the timeline either. If anyone could shed some light on why this happens or perhaps point me in the direction this would be great. The client wants to present the web solution on a safari browser and unfortunately I've not much experience in inner workings of this browser.

[Link to a copy of the work without sensitive information but still has the issue](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73729974/web5/products.html)

Comment: Pretty difficult to debug without seeing the work in progress, or at least its supporting code

Comment: I'll get a version up that takes out the images so i protect my clients work

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73729974/web5/products.html

heres a link, so basically in safari the text will often load with the text in a offset and inappropriate position. the fact that it doesn't always leads me to believe its a bug with safari. also if i inspect it and change a value of the text it will snap in to the correct position. does this help at all?

Answer (score 2):

1. use a div#photo
2. use css for `div#photo div {float:left}`
3. the #photo itself must be floated left to stack them in this horizontal way

HTML:

```
div#album                      {min-width:1000px,min-height:200px}
div#album div                  {float:left,min-width:100px}
div#album div#photo            {min-height:200px}
div#album div#photo div        {float:left}
div#album div#photo div#image  {min-height:200px,min-width:100px}
div#album div#photo div#text   {min-height:50px,min-width:75px}
```

I have given a format, if you look carefully at the dimensions,
what it shows is "make sure your text div does not exceed in height than parent or sibling"

what I have shown is children should have smaller width,height than parents because when using "floats" they spill out

Comment: I'm a bit confused about relating that to my code, breaking it down bit by bit though my divs are floating left :S

Comment: because the plugin uses so many divs i'm struggling to relate each one to your format :S, thank you for the feedback so far.